# Fetching number from contacts but having trouble cleaning the number

Tags: swift

Im fetching the numbers from the contacts list but it gives me "+593 99 999 9999" I'm already doing the following

```
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "")
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\U202a", with: "")
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\U202c", with: "")
item = item.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\U00a0", with: "")
```

My final result is "593 99 999 9999" it's not replacing the \U00a0 occurrence with the code i already have. Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: It should be `"\u{00a0}"` ...

Comment: And you don't want a double backslash, you just want a single backslash.